# Capacitor LocalNotifications - no toast popup on Android?

Tags: android, capacitor

I'm exploring the Capacitor framework at the moment and I'm trying to get Local Notifications to appear as toast popups on the Android Emulator. However they are only appearing in the Notification Panel, signified by an `(i)` icon appearing in the status bar. Additionally, the listener for the `localNotificationReceived` event is never called.

Below is my complete Local Notifications testing component. The example is almost completely lifted from the documentation here:
`https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/apis/local-Notifications`

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import { Plugins } from '@capacitor/core';

class Notifications extends PureComponent {
  componentDidMount = () => {
    Plugins.LocalNotifications
      .addListener("localNotificationReceived", (notification) => {
        console.log('Notification =>', notification);
      });
  }

  schedule = () => {
    Plugins.LocalNotifications.schedule({
      notifications: [{
        title: "Title",
        body: "Body",
        id: 1,
        schedule: { at: new Date(Date.now() + 1000 * 5) },
        sound: 'res://platform_default',
        badge: 1,
        attachments: null,
        actionTypeId: "",
        extra: null
      }],
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.schedule}>
          Schedule Notification in 5 Seconds
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Notifications;
```

Comment: For toast notifications you have toast plugin

Comment: Does local notifications not do this itself? Additionally ‘localNotificationReceived’ isn’t being called, so presently no way to trigger the toast notification?